# Query rows and include rows with columns reversed

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to query a table. I want the results to include the `FROM` and `TO` columns, but then also include rows with these two values reversed. And then I want to eliminate all duplicates. (A duplicate is the same two cities in the same order.)

For example, given this data.

### Trips

```
FROM                 TO
-------------------- --------------------
West Jordan          Taylorsville
Salt Lake City       Ogden
West Jordan          Taylorsville
Sandy                South Jordan
Taylorsville         West Jordan
```

I would want the following results.

```
West Jordan          Taylorsville
Taylorsville         West Jordan
Salt Lake City       Ogden
Ogden                Salt Lake City
Sandy                South Jordan
South Jordan         Sandy
```

I want to do this using C# and Entity Framework, but I could use raw SQL if I need to.

Is it possible to do this in a query, or do I need to manually perform some of this logic?

Comment: Show classes and what you have tried. LINQ query is built from classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: My actual class has much, much more stuff that doesn't clarify the issue. Was there something in particular that wasn't clear from my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I'm following, but doesn't just a simple union work for your sample?

```
select from, to
  from some_table
 union
select to, from
  from some_table
```

Comment: How do you make that unique?

Comment: @JonathanWood I'm not familiar with linq, but the dbms's I've worked with implicitly de-dup with union (as opposed to union all). If linq doesn't do this just wrap a distinct.

Comment: Are you saying `UNION` will remove all rows where all of the columns are the same?

Comment: @JonathanWood Yeah. If by "all of the columns are the same" you mean row duplicates and not column1 = column2.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I mean the same as using `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the first sub query should handle the first part of your question. the `WHERE ID NOT IN` will handle the second part of your question.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Trips
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM Trips t1
        INNER JOIN Trips AS t2
        ON t2.To = t1.From AND t2.From = t1.To
    )
)
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM Trips
    GROUP BY [From], [To]
)
```

I am assuming there is more to the table than just those fields. Usually you have a field (primary key) to uniquely identify the row. I am using `ID` for that field, replace with whatever your table is using.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything.

Comment: I updated my answer to turn it into a `SELECT` query and combined them.